# Data encryption using TRNG

Tags: security, random

I have a true random number generator with me but I am not sure how to use it to encrypt data, because after encryption the data needs to be decrypted. Decryption process needs the same random sequence that was used for encryption. But passing the random sequence along with the encrypted packets is at the cost of security. And generating the same sequence again at the receiver side is highly impossible using the same generator. Kindly suggest a way out!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this. A PRNG can be used only because it is reproducible, as TRNG can only be be as a one-time pad, but you have to copy the pad to be useful.

A PRNG is not necessarily as secure as you might think either. My suggestion is leave secure encryption / decryption algorithms to the experts -- unless you REALLY KNOW what you are doing, all you will have when done is a false sense of security.

ADDED

I have been around for years, I wish I could tell you how many times I seen customers with bad ad-hoc security in place. Encryption done poorly (as is almost certain to be the case for any kind of novice) is really nothing more than obscurity these days. If your data is valuable enough simple obfuscation will only delay the black hats. If you data is not valuable, there is not much reason to encrypt in the first place -- unless you simply want obfuscation, in which simple XOR or and PRNG methods will be perfectly dandy.